# Getting a “not currently available” error when attempting to install Windows 10 on BootCamp on a MacBook Air 2020 running macOS Catalina

Tags: boot-camp, macos-catalina, macbook-air

I tried to install a Windows 10 via bootcamp, but I got stuck with this error:

> “Can’t install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update Server.”

Been searching all possible reasons and fixes. there is even a suggestion that I have to wait hours, days, months. Which is ridiculous. I already spent a whole day with this but still no luck.

I don't have any VPN, I have 50mbps speed internet up/down (fibr), I downloaded ISO file from Windows, tried 3 types of version of window10 still didn’t work.

Comment: Since you can select do download the Windows Support Software from the Boot Camp Assistant without specifying a version of Windows, I would assume the version of Windows 10 is irrelevant.

Comment: A basic Google search shows you are not the only one facing this issue. Here is an official Apple discussion thread: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251931805 Seems to be that Apple is updating their BootCamp related CDN files and honestly that is something you need to wait and see about.

Comment: This is why I hate apple products, to be honest I just helping my friend to install Bootcamp on his new mac been dealing for this 3 days still wont work. Sad to say im in SEA region where in Apple server are terrible. Sad.

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing without the use of the Boot Camp Assistant. The link below will download the Windows Support Software for your Mac.

[Windows Support Software for MacBookAir9,1](http://swcdn.apple.com/content/downloads/16/33/041-84890/kj5efmjgugmbrx9lknsl7ab6ray0ctwf5o/BootCampESD.pkg)

This package will install the `WindowsSupport.dmg` to the `/Library/Applications Support/BootCamp` folder. You can mount this file to access the Windows Support Software files. You need to copy the `$WinPEDriver` and `BootCamp` folder to the root folder of the flash drive holding the Windows 10 files copied from the Windows 10 ISO. The flash drive will probably need to be ExFAT formatted.

> Note: I determined the link the same way Brigadier from GitHub does. I did this manually without the use of Brigadier.